# On hover Animation

Tags: css, animation, hover

Hi I'm working on a small animation (it activates on hover) that i want to make it so that when i hover out of my icon, i want the animation to complete till the end of it anyway, without making it look cut out like broken, does anybody know a solution for that, my code looks something like that:

```
.icon {
  &:hover {
       animation: shake 1s ease infinite;
     }
  }

@keyframes shake {
 0% {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
 }

 50% {
   transform: rotate(30deg);
 }

 100% {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}
```

Comment: your animation has no end. you've set it to repeat infinite number of times. please clarify your question. also, if I understand what I think you want, the solution is going to need to use JS, is that acceptable for you or are you looking for a CSS-only solution?

Comment: i want it to repeat infinite times on hover yes, however is it possible to make it to go back to the start or the end or actually to complete one cicle let's say with CSS only

Comment: sorry @pretzelhammer i had to mention you before i could i have been more clear yes i have to go back and look for animations p.s. have a look at the comment up here

Comment: I don't think a CSS-only solution is possible, I think you'd have to use JS for this.

Comment: Many thanks @pretzelhammer keep up the good work

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
animation: shadow-img 1s linear 2 alternate forwards;
```